# Jenkins HTML publisher plugin when folder name contains a timestamp

Tags: html, jenkins, publish

Hello im using HTML publisher plugin,

But the html files are created in runtime with timestamp for

E:\reports\html\22-08-1982

So how do we specify the "timestamp" folder in the path location

Answer (score 2):

If in your case timestamp means the build timestamp, you can:

- Install [zentimestamp](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin) plugin.
- Go to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure system"
- Enable Global property "Date pattern for the BUILD_TIMESTAMP (build
  timestamp) variable"
- Set "Date and Time pattern" to dd-MM-yyyy
- Save the configuration

Then you can use ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} in HTML publisher plugin, e.g.
HTML directory to archive:

```
reports/html/${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
```

Comment: Interesting but in my case, folder is logged with micro-seconds and so I doubt it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Gatling logs a report folder name that ends with a timestamp containing milliseconds and that folder name is logged in a file called `lastRun.txt` .

[image]